# How to add a link to Browse button shiny app

Tags: css, shiny, text-alignment

I am wondering how to add "Example file" to the Browse button in shiny app, so its aligned nicely? 
I found examples of using tags$ ....  but the link is not aligned properly to the browser button. My results:

[image]

I would like to have it like this:

[image]

My code:

```
tags$a(href ="data/INPUT.txt",
       target="_blank",
       "EXAMPLE_test"), 

fileInput(inputId  = "InputFile",
          label    = "Choose File",
          multiple = TRUE,
          accept   = c("text",
                       "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                       ".txt") )
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fileInput(inputId  = "InputFile",
            label    = tags$a(href = "data/INPUT.txt",
                              target = "_blank",
                              "EXAMPLE_test"),
            multiple = TRUE,
            accept   = c("text",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".txt") )
)
)
```

Comment: Thank you,  this is exactly what I want.